Where does the relative path for the az devops wiki page show --path parameter begin?
Where does the relative path of a wiki page path begin in the URL below?
https://dev.azure.com/Sample-Org/Sample-Project/_wiki/wikis/Sample-Project_wiki/666/Sample-Page
Every combination i've passed in the --path parameter always result in an error:

Wiki page ‘/Sample-Project_wiki/666/Sample-Page’ could not be found. Ensure that the path of the page is correct and the page exists.
Wiki page ‘/666/Sample-Page’ could not be found. Ensure that the path of the page is correct and the page exists.
Wiki page ‘/Sample-Page’ could not be found. Ensure that the path of the page is correct and the page exists.


It would be useful to see the rest of the command you're trying, not just the --path part.

This sample Powershell script worked for me:
$project="MY-PROJECT"
$organization="https://dev.azure.com/MY-ORGANIZATION"
$path="Sample-Project_wiki/666/Sample-Page"
$wiki="$project.wiki"

az devops wiki page show --wiki $wiki --path $path --project $project --organization $organization

In my case, the Wiki name format is {project-name}.wiki:

